# Error while scheduling SSIS package in command Prompt

Tags: ssis, command-prompt

I have an SSIS package, which needs to be deployed by windows scheduler. For testing purpose i have created batch file for the package and ran that batch file in command prompt but its throwing me an error.

my batch file.

```
DTEXEC.exe /F "\\itdv1005083\delete\IntegrationServiceJob_Files\JOBS\MTS\CashSheet_MTS_DataLoad_Jobv01.2.dtsx" /SET \package.Variables[DBUserID].Value;cdouserqa /SET \package.Variables[DBPassword].Value;cdouserqa /SET \package.Variables[DBName].Value;WSODB10_07162010 /SET \package.Variables[DBServer].Value;ITDV1005083 /SET \package.Variables[IntegratedSecurity].Value;True /SET \package.Variables[PwdMatrixServer].Value;ITDV1005083 /SET  \package.Variables[InputFileDirectory].Value;"\\\\boston14.ibt.ibtco.com\Shardata\LST\Test_TXT" /SET
\package.Variables[PeekMatchFileDirectory].Value;"\\\\itdv1005083\delete\IntegrationServiceJob_Files\DIRInput\MTS\Outbound" /SET 
\package.Variables[SourceFileName].Value;MTS_20120106_14544000433.txt  /SET 
\package.Variables[SourceFilePath].Value;"\\\\itdv1005083\delete\IntegrationServiceJob_Files\DIRInput\MTS\Inbound\TestMTS_20120106_14544000433.txt\"
```

When running this command in command Prompt it is throwing following error.

```
Argument "" for option 'set' is not valid.  
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn>\package.Variables[PeekMatchFileDirectory].Value;"\\\\itdv1005083\delete\IntegrationServiceJob_Files\DIRInput\MTS\Outbound" /SET   
\package.Variables[PeekMatchFileDirectory].Value' is not recognized as an interoperable program or batch file.  

same with sourcefilename and source filepath
```

Comment: StackOverflow works on the premise that people want to help each other. A measure of a person's helpfulness & perceived influence on a topic is related to their reputation. You have asked [4 other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1025057/satishkumar?tab=questions) but not selected an answer nor have you upvoted useful answers. People are happy to spend their energy helping you find the answers but you need to be a good member of the community and reward their efforts with votes or feedback if their solutions are not working. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting double quotes around the name of the variable you are trying to set.

For example:

```
/SET "\package.Variables[DBPassword].Value";"cdouserqa"
```